Generate a batch of Abaqus .inp files using Python Multiprocess
I am using a commercial finite element application called Abaqus/CAE with a built-in Python 2.6 interpreter and API.  The inp file is for Abauqus to calculate with having geometry, material properties, boundary condition information. The inp file can be generated by a Python script using the command abaqus cae noGUI=inp.py.
The geomerty that I am trying to generate is a batch of a rectangle with a random circle inside, these do not depend on each other. so I want to use Python multiprocess to generate them in parallel.
The code file name is geninp.py, the details are as follows:
import re
from pathlib import Path
import subprocess
from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor

num_elp = 2
samplesize = 100

thisdir = Path(__file__).resolve().parent

template_path = thisdir / 'template_qfnelpinp.py'


def print_runtime_info(proc: subprocess.Popen, proc_comment: str) -> None:
    while True:
        output = proc.stdout.readline()
        if output == b'' and proc.poll() is not None:
            break
        if output:
            print(output.strip().decode())
    if proc.stderr:
        print(proc.stderr.read().strip().decode())

    print('\n' + '-'*25 + proc_comment + ' finished.' + '-'*25 + '\n')

def run_cmd(cmd: str, cmd_comment: str) -> None:
    try:
        with subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE) as proc:
            print_runtime_info(proc, cmd_comment)
            proc.wait()
    except Exception as e:
        print(f'Error while running {cmd}: {e}')

with open(template_path, 'r') as f:
    file_content = f.read()

def create_and_run(num_seg, inp_idx):
    file_content_new = re.sub(r'{num_seg}', f'{num_seg}', file_content)
    file_content_new = re.sub(r'{inum}', f'{inp_idx}', file_content_new)

    inp_path = thisdir / f'qfnelpinp{num_seg}-{inp_idx}.py'
    with open(inp_path, 'w') as f:
        f.write(file_content)

    cmd = f'abaqus cae noGUI={inp_path}'
    run_cmd(cmd, 'Generate abaqus inp file')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    num_segs = [num_elp for _ in range(samplesize)]
    odb_idxs = range(samplesize)
    with ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=1) as executor:
        executor.map(create_and_run, num_segs, odb_idxs)

There need a template_qnfelpinp.py file, I generate inp.py file from it by modify the num_seg and inum variables. The num_seg is the number of circle, the inum is to label each .inp file.
when I run the code by python3 geninp.py, there is about 40% .inpfile can be generate correctly, others are failed. The failed message is:failed message picture
but when I generate the failed file individually by abaqus cae noGUI=elp2-i.py(i is the label of faild file), that can be done rigtly. This means every elp2-i.py file is right, but that can not be  submitted at the same time by ProcessPoolExecutor.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Why do you read template_path every single time? Do the contents change, or could you read it once at startup? Try only allowing a single process to run at a time so you can debug better. Try outputting more debug info too.



The template_path file is not change, Abaqus software generate .inp file based on a python file inpfile.py, I need to label each .inp file as elp-{num_seg}-{inum}.inp so that eveyelp-{num_seg}-{inum}.inp file can corresponds to itself circle parameter(center and radius). So each inpfile.py with different inum. These inpfile.py does not dependent each other. I want to run (for example 30) process at the same time, the numebr of all .inp file I needed is 3000.


a single process is right, there is not any error.



There's no need to repeat your question I said 1) Can you just read input_path once at startup? 2) Can you try max_workers=1 ?

Oh, thanks, I misunderstood before. That's work after modified by your suggestion. The code I modified as above. but max_workers=1 works well, max_workers=3 still occur error. How can I use max_workers=30 to speed up the calculation successfully?

By the way, the higher value of the max_workers, the higher rate of error Abaqus error. max_workers = 1, error rate is 0%; max_workers = 2, error rate is 10%; max_workers = 8, error rate is 50%.
